# Continuously refreshing part of a webpage after N seconds by calling a function with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, frontend, page-refresh

There have been similar questions like this already on SO. Unfortunately none of them seems to be worked for me.

I have an accordion tab where there can be multiple accordions depending upon the number of devices the logged in user has. I am storing a key for each device in the accordion which I need to pass as a parameter to the function calling to refresh device status.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function(e) {
    var deviceId = $(e.target).attr('device-id');
    var data = {
      'host_name': $(e.target).attr('device-host-name'),
      'host_key': $(e.target).attr('device-host-key')
    };
    updateAppsStatus(deviceId, data)
  });
});

function updateAppsStatus(deviceId, data) {
  var spinner = '<div class="m-3 text-center"><i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i><br>Loading...</div>';
  if ($('#appsStatus-' + deviceId).is(':empty')) {
    $('#appsStatus-' + deviceId).html(spinner);
    $.ajax({
      url: "{{ path('app_apps_status') }}",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: data
    }).done(function(data) {
      $('#appsStatus-' + deviceId).html(data);
    })
  }
  setTimeout(updateAppsStatus, 5000, deviceId, data)
}
```

Comment: As an aside, AJAX polling is an anti-pattern which causes poor server performance. If you need to keep the client UI and server side data in close sync use Websockets instead.

Comment: With regard to your immediate question, provide an anonymous function to `setTimeout()`: `setTimeout(function() { updateAppsStatus(deviceId, data); }, 5000);`. I'd also suggest you put that in the `done()` handler, so you don't queue up multiple requests when they start taking longer than 5 secs.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Made the changes, but still it sends only the first request and no request after that.

Comment: Check that the response from the request is successful.

Comment: `if ($('#appsStatus-' + deviceId).is(':empty'))` then `$('#appsStatus-' + deviceId).html(data);` - looks like it's not going to be empty on subsequent calls, so if you've moved it inside that `if` (eg on the `.done` as suggested) then it'll only make one call.

Comment: Yep the first one is showing correct data with correct apps status. But no more requests after that so setTimeout is not calling the function after the specified time.

Comment: @freedomn-m. Good catch mate. It's working now.